# copying the contents of a binary file

Tags: c, filehandle, copying

I am designing an image decoder and as a first step I tried to just copy the using c. i.e open the file, and write its contents to a new file. Below is the code that I used.

```
while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
  fprintf(fp1,"%c",c);
```

where fp is the source file and fp1 is the destination file.
The program executes without any error, but the image file(".bmp") is not properly copied. I have observed that the size of the copied file is less and only 20% of the image is visible, all else is black. When I tried with simple text files, the copy was complete.

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Title should better be : "Copying the contents of a binary file", this is not specific to images. Retagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the type of the variable `c` is `int`, **not** `char`. In other words, post more code.

This is because the value of the `EOF` constant is typically -1, and if you read characters as `char`-sized values, every byte that is `0xff` will look as the EOF constant. With the extra bits of an `int`; there is room to separate the two.

Comment: Yup that was the mistake, first i tried to directly use the getc() without storing it in a variable. then suddenly i declared a char and used it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you open the files in binary mode?  What are you passing to `fopen`?

Comment: I used r mode, it worked and I also tried with 'rb' aswell. the mistake was that i declared the variable as char. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the most "popular" [**C gotchas**](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2001/02/cfu.html#stdiochar).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fread`and `fwrite` using a block at a time

```
FILE *fd1 = fopen("source.bmp", "r");
FILE *fd2 = fopen("destination.bmp", "w");
if(!fd1 || !fd2)
 // handle open error

size_t l1;
unsigned char buffer[8192]; 

//Data to be read
while((l1 = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fd1)) > 0) {
  size_t l2 = fwrite(buffer, 1, l1, fd2);
  if(l2 < l1) {
    if(ferror(fd2))
      // handle error
    else
      // Handle media full
  }
}
fclose(fd1);
fclose(fd2);
```

It's substantially faster to read in bigger blocks, and fread/fwrite handle only binary data, so no problem with \n which might get transformed to \r\n in the output (on Windows and DOS) or \r (on (old) MACs)

Comment: A very good suggestion, I will also use this in my program and see how it works out. Thanks.