# how to write one binary file to another in c

Tags: c

I have a few binary files that I want to write into an output file.
So I wrote this function using a `char` as a buffer naively thinking it would work.

```
//Opened hOutput for writing, hInput for reading

void faddf(FILE* hOutput, FILE* hInput) {
    char c;
    int scan;
    do{
        scan = fscanf(hInput, "%c", &c);
        if (scan > 0)
          fprintf(hOutput, "%c", c);
    } while (scan > 0 && !feof(hInput));
}
```

Executing this function gives me an output of the few readable `char`'s in the beginning binary file. So I tried it this way:

```
void faddf(FILE* hOutput, FILE* hInput) {
  void * buffer;
  int scan;
  buffer = malloc(sizeof(short) * 209000000);
  fread(buffer, sizeof(short), 209000000, hInput);
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(short), 209000000, hOutput);
  free(buffer);
}
```

This "works" but is only works when the file is smaller then my "magic number" Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copying the contents of a binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757832/copying-the-contents-of-a-binary-file)

Comment: Reading "characters" from a binary file is kind of an oxymoron. Instead read *bytes*, or better yet read *chunks* of bytes. And why would you expect a binary file to be readable?

Comment: You're reading from `hOutput`.

Comment: No `hInput` has the data I want to read and `hOutput` is the file I want to write to.

Comment: Yes but you are giving `hOutput` to the `fscanf()` function.

Comment: that is a mistake,  I must of made it in copying over I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: Use `fread` and `fwrite` instead of `fscanf` and `fprintf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your new code (in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364635/3386109)) is much better than the old code, it can still be improved and simplified.

Specifically, you can avoid any memory problems by copying the file in chunks.

```
void faddf( FILE *fpout, FILE *fpin )
{
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t count;

    while ( (count = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fpin)) > 0 )
        fwrite(buffer, 1, count, fpout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid reading *bytes per byte*. Use the `fgets()` function instead of `fscanf().`

Please refer to : [Man fgets() (for Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/c37dh6kf.aspx)

When you open both files next to each other (input one / output one), you're saying that the output file only contains readable characters... But can your text editor display unreadable characters on the input one ?

Comment: Still, reading "lines" from a binary file is just as much an oxymoron as reading "characters". I would suggest using `fread` and `fwrite` instead.

Comment: Oh yeah that was the function I was looking for. I could'nt remember it's name. You're right.

Comment: The data that I am reading unfortunately has poor string representation as it has low value characters mixed in with readable characters: 0x00 - 0xff

Comment: Ok, but how do you determine that some characters are missing ?
Check the number of bytes read, or even the file size...

Answer (score 1):

I should not have asked the question in the first place but here is how I ended up doing it:

```
void faddf(FILE* hOutput, FILE* hInput) {
    void * buffer;
    int scan,size;
    size_t read;

    //get the input file size
    fseek(hInput, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(hInput);
    fseek(hInput, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    //place the get space
    buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer == NULL)exit(1);//should fail silently instead

    //try to read everything to buffer
    read = fread(buffer, 1, size, hInput);

    //write what was read
    fwrite(buffer, 1, read, hOutput);

    //clean up
    free(buffer);
}
```